# Find differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

Given the differential equation $y''+a(t)y'+b(t)y=0$, it has a solution $y(t) = t$ for $t>0$. Suppose that the Wronskian associated with two linearly independent solutions has the form $W(t) = 1-\ln(t)$. Determine the functions $a(t)$ and $b(t)$ explicitly.

My steps:

1. After hours of work, I found the second soluction is $y_2(t) = \ln(t)$

My question is any idea to use this information, to find $a(t)$ and $b(t)$.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There are basically two ways to solve this problem.

**The first method**, which you start to follow, needs to find the second solution to the differential equation thanks to the given Wronskian. Indeed, since $W = y_1y_2' - y_1'y_2 = 1 - \ln t$, with $y_1(t) = t$, we end up with an inhomogeneous linear first-order differential equation for $y_2(t)$, namely $ty_2' - y_2 = 1 - \ln t$. Applying the method of variation of the parameter to this last equation, we get $y_2(t) = \ln t$, which you have determined already.

Now, since $y_1$ and $y_2$ both satisfy the original differential equation, we can write two equations for the unknown functions $a(t)$ and $b(t)$, i.e.
$$
\begin{cases}
   y_1'' + ay_1' + by_1 = 0 \\
   y_2'' + ay_2' + by_2 = 0
\end{cases}
$$
Those equations are linear, this is why we can recast them as the following matrix equation :
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
   y_1' & y_1 \\
   y_2' & y_2 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
   a \\
   b 
\end{pmatrix}
= -
\begin{pmatrix}
   y_1'' \\
   y_2'' 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
or, more explicitly,
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
   1 & t \\
   1/t & \ln t 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
   a \\
   b 
\end{pmatrix}
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
   0 \\
   1/t^2 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
I let you finish and invert this equation.

**The second method** is more direct and doesn't require a second solution. It is based on the fact that the Wronskian satisfy $W' = -aW$, hence $a = -\frac{W'}{W} = \frac{1}{t(1-\ln t)}$ in the present case. In consequence, we have straightforwardly $b = -\frac{y_1''+ay_1'}{y_1} = -\frac{1}{t^2(1-\ln t)}$.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't specify the method you utilized in order to find that second solution, i'm going to inform the whole process i thought:

First instinct is to compute the Wronskian using the solution you already have to try and find the second solution. This will give rise to another differential equation:

$$t\frac{dy_2(t)}{dt}-y_2=1-\ln(t)$$

Which constitutes a first order homogeneous differential equation. You can solve for $y_2(t)$ (divide the entire equation by $t$ and try to force the product rule of derivatives on the left hand side using a function $u(t)$). Then, with the second solution at hand, substitute both solutions in the original differential equation and find $a(t)$ and $b(t)$.